# Использование значения переменной в качестве имени передаваемого в запросе параметра

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как использовать значение переменной в качестве имени передаваемого параметра в Ajax-запросе?

То есть чтобы получился элемент `$_POST['specialName'];`

Текущий код:

```
sampleName = "specialName";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        sampleName: value
    },
    success: function(data) {};
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно объект `data` создать заранее, задав нужный ключ с помощью `[]`:

```js
var url = "/";
var sampleName = "specialName";
var data = {};
data[sampleName] = 123;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: data
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли!